# robot.getColorPixel() returns the wrong color?

Tags: java, colors, awtrobot

In my program i use the java Robots method: `robot.getPixelColor(x, y);`

Since this is sRGB ColorSpace, i convert it to RGB Color Space using the following code.

When i open MS Paint, and paint everything black, my java Program prints `2, 2, 2` instead of the expected `0, 0, 0`.

```
int pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(x, y).getRGB();
int blue = pixelColor & 0xff;
int green = (pixelColor & 0xff00) >> 8;
int red = (pixelColor & 0xff0000) >> 16;
System.out.println(red+", "+green+", "+blue);
```

Comment: Im using Sublime Text for this code.

Comment: What does  robot.getPixelColor(x, y).getRGB(); return?

Comment: for black it returns 
-16645630, for white it returns -1

Comment: Apparently when i change int pixelColor to Integer pixelColor, my output is not 2, 2, 2 but 1, 1, 1

Comment: Paint is generating 0, 0, 0 same for GIMP and paint.net.

Comment: Seperating it results in the same 1, 1, 1 @user85421

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 different External programs, and it seems as if my Monitor is displaying wrong colors, as those showed 1, 1, 1 for black (0, 0, 0).

**FIX:**
**Reset your AMD / Nvidia Drivers Color settings, and restart your PC.**